# how to have multiple mongodb connections and listen to 1 port 8080

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, connection

my project have 1 react component that contain sub-component. Each component may have 1 mongodb database.i been wondering how to have multiple db?

my code so far can only connect to 1 db
in **db** i have **connection.js** as:

```
require("dotenv").config();

let mongoose = require("mongoose");
let mongoDB = process.env.DB_CONNECTION;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
let connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.on(
  "error",
  console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:")
);

module.exports = connection;
```

in **app.js** i have:

```
const connection = require("./db/connection");
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("connected to db");
  const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT1 || 8081, () => {
    console.log("listening on " + `${process.env.PORT1 || 8081}`);
  });
});
```

How can i have another db (eg: **/db/secondDatabase.js** that same as the first db) and add it to **app.js**? many thanks in advance, i appreciate your help!!!

Comment: You can refer this tutorial: https://dev.to/ziishaned/open-multiple-mongodb-connection-in-express-js-app-36be

Comment: Wow thank you for such amazing link!!! i get it run as i wanted : D again, thank you so much @AjitKumar < 3

Comment: Some days before, I was also looking for this. Then, I found this article and it seemed to me - resourceful. Any way Welcome !